# Select data from table join or UDPATE?

Tags: postgresql, performance, update

I have a question regarding PostgreSQL DB performance.  I am given a CSV file with a lot of rows (let's say around 1 million rows) that represents updates to a database table (let's call it MY_TABLE).  I would like to copy the data into MY_TABLE from the CSV file.  It is presumed that all the rows in the CSV are updates to the data in MY_TABLE and are not new inserts.  I have 2 options for doing this, and I would like to know which one I should expect to be more performant and why (if possible):

Option 1:

1) Create a secondary table, let's say TEMP_TABLE.
2) Upload all the data from the CSV into TEMP_TABLE.
3) Natural join (on PK) MY_TABLE x TEMP_TABLE.
4) Select rows from MY_TABLE x TEMP_TABLE into MY_TABLE where the PK from the join matches the PK in MY_TABLE.

Option 2:

1) Create a SQL script on client-side containing N UPDATE operations of the form:

`UPDATE MY_TABLE SET VALUES (data-from-csv) WHERE MY_TABLE.PK = (PK-data-from-csv)`

where N is the number of rows in the CSV.

2) Upload that script to the database and execute it.

Which of these options is more performant and why?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that Option 2 is more preferable because of the following:

1. Less overall writes to the database (no extra table required)
2. Less overall WAL activity (Option 1 involves both an `INSERT`/`COPY` and an `UPDATE` for each row involved)

In either case, you could encounter some table bloat, in which case you'd want to make sure you `VACUUM` after doing this operation.

Comment: if TEMP_TABLE is truly a temp table, then COPY into it does not generate WAL.

Comment: Right--if `TEMP_TABLE` is created as a `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` or `CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE`, then you don't generate WAL.

Answer (score 0):

The temp table is probably preferable.  Parsing the same UPDATE statement one million times is going to get slow.  Opening and closing transactions one million times can also be slow, but you can put all updates into a single transaction if you want.  By having separate update statements you are basically forcing it to use a nested-loop plan, where the loop is implemented externally.  By doing it in bulk, you allow it to use some other plan, like a hash join or a merge join.  (Whether those will actually be faster is another question--maybe they are, maybe not.  A lot will depend on your memory settings and how much of the table is already in memory).

The best way to find out which is faster is to try it.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to put all the updates into one single transaction, that was my plan.